# Cannot access Web API CORE 3.0 from Postman calls

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman, .net-core-3.1

I am testing simple .NET Web API CORE 3.1 and have setup simple methods by following tutorial on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio. I have managed to run Web API but couldn't make calls from Postman/

[image]

### Controller

```
namespace CoreAPIApplication.Controllers
{
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TodoItemsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly TodoContext _context;

    public TodoItemsController(TodoContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TodoItem>>> GetTodoItems()
    {
        return await _context.TodoItems.ToListAsync();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> GetTodoItem(long id)
    {
        var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);

        if (todoItem == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return todoItem;
    }

    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutTodoItem(long id, TodoItem todoItem)
    {
        if (id != todoItem.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(todoItem).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!TodoItemExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(TodoItem todoItem)
    {
        _context.TodoItems.Add(todoItem);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = todoItem.Id }, todoItem);
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> DeleteTodoItem(long id)
    {
        var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.FindAsync(id);
        if (todoItem == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.TodoItems.Remove(todoItem);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return todoItem;
    }

    private bool TodoItemExists(long id)
    {
        return _context.TodoItems.Any(e => e.Id == id);
    }
 }
}
```

[image]

[image]

I have tried postman with and without SSL certificate enable from postman setting but still no result

Answer (score 1):

From Startup.cs comment out

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

and use http://localhost:5000

If you do need to run it on https, you may need to have a certificate.
You can create one by running : "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" in your terminal/cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Can you enable CorsPolicy by adding this => [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")] on the top of your controller class.

```
namespace CoreAPIApplication.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
```

Comment: I have tried but it is not working... I cannot access the API endpoint on localhost browser neither. it seems to do something with proxy

Comment: I would recommend try to use swagger to test your API. Swagger is the best option for testing your API.